# Alipay payment gateway integration : ILLEGAL_SIGN error

Tags: c#, integration, payment-gateway, payment, alipay

**ALIPAY PAYMENT GATEWAY RETURNS WITH "ILLEGAL_SIGN" ERROR.**

I am new to payment gateway integration. I have been attempting to test alipay payment gateway (test environment).

At first, I opened a test-environment account which provides me 
"Cross-border Online Payment(PC)" credentials.

Here, alipay shows how a request should be sent.
https://global.alipay.com/service/website/8

I followed above link and tried with my own credentials (i.e. my sign-type, sign, out_trade_no etc).

However, alipay throws "ILLEGAL_SIGN" error in return. Can you please guide me through what I am supposed to do?

[image]

Here is the url that i am hitting:

https://mapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?subject=Beautylish&sign_type=MD5&out_trade_no=1115919735609649&currency=USD&total_fee=2.2&partner=2088621921925641&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alipay.com&sendFormat=normal&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alipay.com&sign=zwy07ak84xjo0oiet8vw41rg5rcsuxp4&_input_charset=UTF-8&service=create_forex_trade

I am searching through online, nothing seems to solve my issue. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you request supports UTF-8. The problem is on the requesting side of this any unfortunately the question doesn't provide that information.

Comment: You said,"Make sure you request supports UTF-8".
May I know how I can make sure that my request supports UTF-8?

Comment: Depends on how you are making the request. AJAX, OkHttp, NSURLSession?